Does the inverse of this function exsist?
For a personal project i derived the function,
$$f(x) = x^{\left(\frac{c+1}{x^b+d}+1\right)}$$
where $b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} |b,c,d > 0$ (I think that is how you write it, i am still learningD:)
I would like to find the exact inverse, $f^{-1}(x)$. Otherwise known as, "solve for $x$". However, all my attempts thus far have failed. I always end up with either an Nth powered root or exponential fraction containing $x^b$. And then i get stuck. It seems the big issue is the $x^b$ term. Using numerical methods, a friend of mine found this;

But they also called into question if an exact inverse actually exists. Even my math prof was like bru. So i suspect there just is not exact inverse.
My core question is if an exact expression for $f^{-1}(x)$ exists. If so, i mean i feel like to answer this you would have to compute it but idk.

Do you mean $\dfrac{x^c+1}{x^b+d}+1$?

@ultralegend5385 lemme add parentheses

The typical step would be to take the derivative and check its sign.

Judging by the graph, the inverse should exist since the function seems to be bijective. But I would bet considerable amounts of money on the fact that the inverse is not an elementary function (i.e., cannot be expressed in terms of trigonometric functions, exponents, fractions, products and sums)

@5xum Thanks for the comment, what makes you think that it is not elementary ? The friend who made the graph said he thinks the inverse is non transcendental, but idk what that means or if it is related to what you said

@ErikHall Once you start mixing polynomials and exponentials, elementary inverses usually fly right out the window. For example, $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ famously has a non-elementary inverse. I don't know how to actually prove that a function is or is not elementary though, so this is just a gut guess.

@5xum it looks like you're confusing inverses with antiderivatives. The example you give has an especially simple inverse of the form $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{\log x}$

@NinadMunshi maybe 5xum was thinking about multi-branched inverse of $xe^x$?

@NinadMunshi You're right, I was trigger happy and gave a bad example.

Did you want an integral/series representation of the inverse?
